# How to create programmatically tsdb wal or block for Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus

I need to generate a sample data for Prometheus and trying to create a script that will programmatically create the tsdb block. With the help of ChatGPT I've written this code, it creates the WAL block that accepted by Prometheus and even the series name detected by autocomplete but I don't see any values, why?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/prometheus/prometheus/model/labels"
    "github.com/prometheus/prometheus/storage"
    "github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tsdb"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new TSDB instance
    db, err := tsdb.Open(
        "./data", // directory where the data will be stored
        nil,      // a logger (can be nil for no logging)
        nil,      // an optional prometheus.Registerer
        tsdb.DefaultOptions(),
        nil,
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening TSDB:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Create a new appender
    app := db.Appender(context.Background())

    // Create labels for the gauge time series
    lbls := labels.FromStrings("__name__", "example_gauge", "type", "gauge")

    // Initialize a SeriesRef
    var ref storage.SeriesRef

    // Add some data points
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        var err error
        ref, err = app.Append(ref, lbls, time.Now().Unix()+int64(i), float64(i))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error appending:", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }

    // Commit the data
    err = app.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error committing:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the code above works, the only issue was that I need to pass the time in ms and `time.Now().Unix()` returns it in seconds, so you need to multiply it by 1000, so changing this line will give you the result:

from:

```
ref, err = app.Append(ref, lbls, time.Now().Unix()+int64(i), float64(i))
```

to:

```
ref, err = app.Append(ref, lbls, (time.Now().Unix()+int64(i)) * 1000, float64(i))
```